# How does Ogre share singleton object in different DLLs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, ogre

In **OgreMain** project

**OgrePrerequisites.h**

```
#define _OgreExport __declspec( dllexport )
```

**OgreSingleton.h**

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton
{
private:
    Singleton(const Singleton<T> &);
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton<T> &);
protected:
    static T* msSingleton;
public:
    Singleton(void)
    {
        assert(!msSingleton);
        msSingleton = static_cast<T*>(this);
    }
    ~Singleton(void)
    {
        assert(msSingleton);  msSingleton = 0;
    }
    static T& getSingleton(void)
    {
        assert(msSingleton);  return (*msSingleton);
    }
    static T* getSingletonPtr(void)
    {
        return msSingleton;
    }
};
```

**OgreRoot.h**

```
class _OgreExport Root : public Singleton<Root>
{
};
```

Files above are compiled into **OgreMain.lib**

In **RenderSystem_GL** project

**OgreGLPlugin.cpp**

```
void GLPlugin::install()
{
    mRenderSystem = new GLRenderSystem();

    Root::getSingleton().addRenderSystem(mRenderSystem);
}
```

**OgreGLPlugin.cpp** is compiled into **RenderSystem_GL.dll**

Ogre share a unique `Root` object in **OgreMain** and **RenderSystem_GL**. How did Ogre make it?

---

Here is my code.

class `DllDemoA` in **DllDemoA.dll**

```
class __declspec(dllexport) DllDemoA: public Singleton<DllDemoA>
{
public:
    DllDemoA()
    {
        // always assert error
        DllDemoB::getSingleton();
    }
};

__declspec(dllexport) void Create()
{
    DllDemoA* a = new DllDemoA();
}
```

class `DllDemoB` in **DllDemoB.lib**

```
class __declspec(dllexport) DllDemoB: public Singleton<DllDemoB>
{
};
```

**main.exe** link **DllDemoB.lib**, dynamically load **DllDemoA.dll**

```
int main()
{
    DllDemoB* b = new DllDemoB();
    // no assert error
    DllDemoB::getSingleton();
    HINSTANCE hMod = LoadLibrary("DllDemoA.dll");
    typedef void(*Func)();
    Func func = (Func)GetProcAddress(hMod, "Create");
    if (func)
    {
        func();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out what you are asking. Is this a question about how template base classes interact with DLLs, or about the Ogre Root singleton object itself?

Comment: Just about share singleton object in DLLs. In my code, I create a singleton object of DllDemoB in **main.exe**, when I want to use this object in **DllDemoA.dll**(`DllDemoB::getSingleton();`), I get an assert error(`assert(msSingleton);  return (*msSingleton);`).

Comment: You're entering a world of pain because you're trying to mix dynamic loading of DLLs with c++ objects. OgreMain is dynamically linked, not dynamically loaded.

Comment: Yes, OgreMain is statically loading and dynamically linking, but render system plugins are dynamically loading and linking. I have found an answer to my question from [Ogre forums](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=69311). Thanks for your help.